# how to make JTable cell non editable but should be able to select and copy the value in current cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable, awt, tablecelleditor

I am trying to make JTable cells non-editable but if i do so Iam unable to select a single cell value instead  when i try to copy the entire row is getting selected
I want to copy only the selected cell value instead of entire row.Is there a way to do it?

```
public class EmployeeWin extends JFrame {

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel() {
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column){
                return false;
            }
        };
        Container cont = this.getContentPane();
        JTable tab = new JTable(model);
        private TableRowSorter<TableModel> rowSorter = new TableRowSorter<>(model);
        private final JTextField searchFilter = new JTextField();

        public EmpDataWin(List<EmployeeDTO> pEmployeeDTO) {
            initialize(pEmployeeDTO);
        }

        public void initialize(List<EmployeeDTO> pEmployeeDTOList) {

            JPanel panelParent = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

            // Add Header

            model.addColumn("Employee Name");
            model.addColumn("Department");
            model.addColumn("Details");

           // Add data row to table

            for (EmployeeDTO aEmployeeDTO : pEmployeeDTOList) {
                model.addRow(new Object[] { aEmployeeDTO.getEmployee_Name(), aEmployeeDTO.getDepartment(),
                        aEmployeeDTO.getDetails()});
            }

            tab.setRowSorter(rowSorter);
            tab.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);


            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            panel.add(new JLabel(UIConstants.SEARCH), BorderLayout.WEST);
            JTextField searchFilter = SearchFilter.createRowFilter(tab);
            panel.add(searchFilter, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

            tab.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
            JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(tab,ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            panelParent.add(panel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
            panelParent.add(sp,BorderLayout.CENTER);
            panelParent.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10 , 10, 10, 10));
            cont.add(panelParent);
            this.pack();

                }

                public static void main(String[] args) {

                    EmployeeDAO dao = new EmployeeDAO();
                    List<EmployeeDTO> dto = dao.getemployeeData();

                    JFrame frame = new EmployeeDataWin(dto);
               }

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when i try to copy the entire row is getting selected I want to copy only the selected cell value instead of entire row

The default `Action` for the `Ctrl+C` key is to copy the entire row. If you only want the data of the currently selected cell then you need to replace the default `Action` with a custom `Action`.

The logic would be something like:

```
Action copyCell = new AbstractAction()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JTable table = (JTable)e.getSource();
        int row = table.getSelectedRow();
        int column = table.getSelectedColumn();
        Object value = table.getValueAt(row, column);

        // copy the data to the clipboard

        Clipboard c = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        StringSelection testData = new StringSelection( value.toString() );
        c.setContents(testData, testData);
    }
};

table.getActionMap().put("copy", copyCell);
```

The above code will create the custom `Action` and replace it in the `ActionMap` of the `JTable`. See [Key Bindings](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/). The program provided in the link shows all the default Actions and the keyword for each Action.

Comment: Add a `JPopupMenu` (using the same `Action`) and you have sweet solution